# InApp purchase: how to give an item to an user for free

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have an app that has a "premium" mode, that users can buy as in-app purchase. I use managed IAP for this.
To certain users I would like to give that premium mode for free, for example because they helped me in resolving some issues.
Is there a way to do it, besides sending them a modified apk?

Thank you.

Comment: it u want to implement InApp PUrcharged?

Answer (score -1):

Read it carefully it will help u
http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html

Comment: Besides giving me the link to the official documentation, do you know if it is possible to do it? I cannot find it.

Comment: Can you tell me how? I cannot find a way.